# How to handle and execute multiple SQL at once in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mysql-python

I am trying to execute multiple query in a `for-loop`. So in each `loop`, if either `query` failed to execute, all `queries` in that `loop` will not commit to `database` and return the error message for failed `query`. Below is my code. Seems even there is one `query` failed to run, the others queries will still execute and commit the data to `database`. How can I change it to achieve what I want? Thanks

Code:

```
import mysql.connector 
mydb = mysql.connector.connect() 
cursor = mydb.cursor()
for i in country_list:
    try:
        query1 = "call_sp_insert_sth_1" //insert data to DB
        query2 = "call_sp_insert_sth_2" //insert data to DB
        query3 = "call_sp_insert_sth_3" //update data to DB
        cursor.execute(query1)
        cursor.execute(query2)
        cursor.execute(query3)
        mydb.commit()
    except Exceptiion as err:
        fail_list.append('error':err.msg)
        continue

mysql.connector.close_connection(mydb)
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear -- are you saying that if query3 fails, you want query1 and query2 to be rolled back?

Comment: @JohnGordon yes

Comment: @WILLIAM . . . It is possible that the stored procedures themselves commit the changes to the database so this could be tricky.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to combine the three queries into one stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would write your code.

```
import mysql.connector 
mydb = mysql.connector.connect() 
cursor = mydb.cursor()
query1 = "call_sp_insert_sth_1" //insert data to DB
query2 = "call_sp_insert_sth_2" //insert data to DB
query3 = "call_sp_insert_sth_3" //update data to DB

for i in country_list:
  try:
    with mydb.cursor() as curs:
      cursor.execute(query1)
      cursor.execute(query2)
      cursor.execute(query3)
      curs.close()
  except Exception as err:
    fail_list.append('error':err.msg)
  else:
    mydb.commit()
```

I tend to have my queries as variables outside the for loop with parameters, then populate the parameters in the loop.

```
myquery = '''select * from {}'''
for table in tables:
  curs.execute(myquery.format(table))
```

The 'else' part only kicks off if there were no errors in the 'try' part.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `mydb` connection to not auto-commit.

```
mydb.autocommit = False
```